# Overloading operator=() with callback

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading

I have a template `Property` which wraps a data and provides other services. This template is specialized for basic data (float, int_32, bool...) and there exists another specilization for vectors of basic types. Something like:

```
template<typename T>
Property : public PropertyBase
{
public:
    // Base types specilization.
    void operator=(T const & data);
}

template<typename T>
Property<std::vector<T> > : public PropertyBase
{
public:
    // Specilization for vectors of base types.
    T const & operator[](std::size_t i) const;
}
```

On the specilization for basic data I have overloaded `operator=` so that a callback is called after the data was changed. On the specilization for vectors I have overloaded `operator[]` to get indexed access to the ith element of the vector.

Now I would like to get a similar behavior that I have for `operator=` on basic types but with my specialization for vectors. I am stuck though. What I would like to do is something like:

```
Property<std::vector<float> > myProp;
myProp[5] = 5.21f;
```

and expect the callback to be called after the assignement happened.

The problem is that `myProp[5]` returns a float, and the callback mechanism is not defined for floats but Property.

Of course I can write an indexed setter function such as

```
template<typename T>
Property<std::vector<T> > : public PropertyBase
{
public:
    // Specilization for vectors of base types.
    T const & operator[](std::size_t i) const;

    void set(int i, T const & newValue);
}
```

But with the setter the syntax is not as clean as I would expect.

I can also call the callback in `operator[]` but then the callback is called before the assigment, not after.

Anyone has an idea to get this clean syntax while still being able to call my callback after the assigment?

Thanks!

**PS:** note that my `Property` templates are more complex than what is written and do check whether T is a base type or not (which is not done here) but this is not relevant for my question.

Comment: I believe that you would have to write another overload for operator= that would explicitly take a float type. How would you differentiate in between T and float (because your 'data' argument could in fact be anything)?

Comment: Make sure to read Item 30 of [More Effective C++](http://www.amazon.com/More-Effective-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/020163371X)

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to return a proxy from your `operator[]()` which [implicitly] converts to your type `T` and has an assignment operator intercepting the assignment. Here is a sketch:

```
template <typename T>
class proxy {
    Property<std::vector<T>>* property;
    std::size_t               index;
public:
    proxy(Property<std::vector<T>>* property, std::size_t index)
        : property(property)
        , index(index) {
    }
    operator T const&() const { return property->get(index); }
    T const& operator= (T const& other) {
        return this->property->set(index);
    }
};
```

Your `operator[]()` would then return such a proxy:

```
 template <typename T>
 proxy<T> Property<std::vector<T>>::operator[](std::size_t index) {
     return proxy<T>(this, index);
 }
```

The actual interception of the reading and writing of the fields would happen in the corresponding `set()` and `get()` members. These can be `private` if `proxy<T>` is made `friend` of the class. The main issue with using a proxy class like this is that it doesn't allow the use of member functions, e.g.:

```
Property<std::vector<std::string>> p;
p[0].c_str();
```

Since `p[0]` happens to be a `proxy<T>` it doesn't have a `.c_str()` function. Since you stated that you are only supporting certain basic types you could support the suitable operations on the proxy. The other issue with using a proxy type is that it takes out one of the conversions and, strictly speaking, an iterator returning proxies rather than references isn't a proper iterator (although I seem to recall that the iterator requirements were relaxed in C++11).

Comment: Mostly right, but returning a (non-const) `T&` creates the possibility for the data to change other than through assignment, which means missed callbacks.

Comment: One can enable direct `const` member access (using `->`) via `const T* proxy::operator->() const { return &get(); }`  non-`const` member access of course would create new holes in the callback system.

Comment: I wonder if `operator=` shouldn't `return (*this)` (with type `proxy<T>&`)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I have fixed the problem with returning `T&` rather than `T const&`. Based on the question member access shouldn't be a problem. With respect to the result of `operator=()`: I'm not sure. I vaguely recall that the result of proxies assignment was discussed in the past and both types have their advantages.

Comment: @Dietmar & Ben: This is a very interesting approach! I am not sure I understand when you say "it takes out one of the conversions and, strictly speaking, an iterator returning proxies rather than references isn't a proper iterator" though. Can you give more details?

Comment: @arennuit: Assume you have an iterator returning proxies. Iterators are meant to support `T* r = &*it;` but since `*it` returns a proxy that isn't the case (you can make this particular case work but there are still others which let you detect that `*it` isn't a reference). With respect to the conversion: let's say you have a function `f(S)` and `T` implicitly converts to `S`. You could use `f(t)` if `t` is an object of type `T` but you can't use `f(v[0])` if `v[0]` returns a proxy because the compiler will only do one conversion and that is used to go from the proxy to `T`.